Dockerize Duende Identity Server: "Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44384/.well-known/openid-configuration'.Connection refused"
I am trying to dockerize my pet project on a microservice architecture. I have several microservices, a client and duende identity server. Locally, on my machine, the client communicates directly with the duende server. When I click Login it throws me to the identity server host where I register or authenticate and I am returned back to the client host with an authorization cookie. When I dockerize my project and specify localhost identity server for connection I get the error "Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44384/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Connection refused".
If I enter this link just in the browser manually: https://localhost:44384/.well-known/openid-configuration, I get the required json response. If I specify the internal address of the docker https://app.service.identity I get an error that the page is not found, because it throws me to this link, which exists only inside the docker. How can I fix this?
docker-compose.yml:
x-app-default-env: &app-default-env
  Logging__LogLevel__Default: Information
  Logging__LogLevel__Microsoft.AspNetCore: Warning
  AllowedHosts: "*"

services:
  app:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.web
    build:
      context: ./Mango.Web
    volumes:
      - ./Mango.Web/wwwroot:/app/wwwroot
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ServiceUrls__IdentityAPI: https://localhost:44384
      ServiceUrls__ProductAPI: http://app.service.product
      ServiceUrls__CouponAPI: http://app.service.coupon
      ServiceUrls__ShoppingCartAPI: http://app.service.shoppingcart
      ServiceUrls__AzureBlobAPI:
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=MangoWEBAPI"

  app.service.order:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.services.order
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Mango.Services.OrderAPI/Dockerfile
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=MangoOrderAPI"
      ConnectionStrings__AzureServiceBus: ${AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING}
      CheckoutMessageTopic: "checkoutmessagetopic"
      CheckoutSubscription: "mangoOrdersSubscription"
      OrderPaymentProcessTopic: "orderpaymentprocesstopic"
      OrderPaymentProcessSubscription: "mangoPayment"
      OrderUpdatePaymentResultTopic: "orderupdatepaymentresulttopic"
      OrderUpdatePaymentResultSubscription": "mangoOrdersSubscription"
      CheckoutMessageQueue: "checkoutqueue"
    
      
  app.service.azureblobservice:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.services.azureblobservice
    build: Mango.Services.AzureBlobService
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ServiceUrls__IdentityServer: http://app.service.identity
      ConnectionStrings__BlobStorage: ${CONNECTION_STRINGS_BLOB_STORAGE}
      BlobContainerName: ${BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME}
      
  app.service.product:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.services.productapi
    build: Mango.Services.ProductAPI
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=MangoProductAPI"

  app.service.payment:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.services.payment
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Mango.Services.PaymentAPI/Dockerfile
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ServiceUrls__IdentityServer: http://app.service.identity
      ConnectionStrings__AzureServiceBus: ${AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING}
      OrderPaymentProcessTopic: "orderpaymentprocesstopic"
      OrderPaymentProcessSubscription: "mangoPayment"
      OrderUpdatePaymentResultTopic: "orderupdatepaymentresulttopic"
      OrderUpdatePaymentResultSubscription: "mangoOrdersSubscription"
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=MangoPaymentAPI"

  app.service.shoppingcart:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.services.shoppingcart
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Mango.Services.ShoppingCartAPI/Dockerfile
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ServiceUrls__IdentityServer: http://app.service.identity
      ServiceUrls__CouponAPI: http://app.service.coupon
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=MangoShoppingCartAPI"

  app.service.identity:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.services.identity
    build: Mango.Services.Identity
    volumes:
      - ./Mango.Services.Identity/wwwroot:/app/wwwroot
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=MangoIdentityAPI"

  app.service.email:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.services.email
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Mango.Services.Email/Dockerfile
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ConnectionStrings__AzureServiceBus: ${AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING}
      OrderUpdatePaymentResultTopic: "orderupdatepaymentresulttopic"
      EmailSubscription: "emailSubscription"
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=MangoEmailAPI"

  app.service.coupon:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mango.services.coupon
    build: Mango.Services.CouponAPI
    environment:
      <<: *app-default-env
      ServiceUrls__IdentityServer:
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=MangoCouponAPI"

docker-compose.override.yml:
services:
  app:
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 44315:443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
  
  app.service.identity:
    ports:
      - 44384:443
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro

  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    image: postgres:16
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ../docker/db/data:/var/lib/pgsql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres

Client Program.cs Authorization:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
}).AddCookie("Cookies", c => c.ExpireTimeSpan=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["ServiceUrls:IdentityAPI"];
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.ClientId = "mango";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("sub", "sub", "sub");
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        options.Scope.Add("mango");
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true
        };
    });



The problem is that from within the containers, they do not trust https://localhost:44384  (localhost certificate) ,use HTTP between containers and always HTTPS from the browser point of view. or install a certifcate inside the docker containers so that they can trust HTTPS.

@ToreNestenius I added certificates for each container

What is the result? try to make a CURL request from one container to the other and see if that works. Also ,  you need to specify the name of the target container, localhost https://localhost:44384 points to itself.... you typically dont use https://localhost:44384 across containers.

@ToreNestenius I made a curl request, if I do curl "https://app.service.identity/.well-known/openid-configuration" Error: "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate" curl https://localhost:44384/.well-known/openid-configuration Error:curl:Failed to connect to localhost port 44384: Connection refused. If on internal ports, it just returns nothing, but no errors either.
I need to specify an external host, because I redirect to another service, if I specify an internal host and http,then in the browser I am redirected to it,but in the public DNS such an address is not available

In the AddOpenIdConnect options, you have two parameters: the Authority, where the browser will redirect to, and MetadataAddress, where your client will call to get the discovery document. you can use HTTP with the metaddaa address and HTTPS with the authority, that is the public DNS domian.

@ToreNestenius
Now I'm getting this error:
SocketException: Connection refused
System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpRequestException: Connection refused (app.service.identity:80)
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(string host, int port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://app.service.identity'.

First step is to ensure that one container can talk to another container over HTTP, port 80.. Then you can consider if you need HTTPS as well, but usually, within Dockersystem, often HTTP is good enough.  HTTPS is only required between the browser and the client/IdentityServer. Not between the containers.

@ToreNestenius I fixed that error, now I'm getting another one: JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://app.service.identity'. Will retry at '10/09/2024 06:47:51 +00:00'. But when I do "curl http://app.service.identity/.well-known/openid-configuration" I get a normal json response

might be that it received XML or HTML (the < value) instead of JSON that it expects. do you CURL from within the client container?

@ToreNestenius yes i do curl from the client and receive normal json

it might be that the URL your application is not actually the same as the one you CURL. I added an answer how you can diagnose the back channel traffic

To diagnose and debug the communication between the client and IdentityServer, then you can use some code like:
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.BackchannelHttpHandler = new JwtBearerBackChannelListener();
    opt.BackchannelTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);         //default 60s
    ...
}

.AddOpenIdConnect(opt =>
{
    opt.BackchannelHttpHandler = new JwtBearerBackChannelListener();
    opt.BackchannelTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);         //default 60s
    ...
}

Then, a sample back channel listener can look like this:
namespace Infrastructure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Backchannel listener, that will log requests made to our IdentityServer 
    /// From the IdentityServer in production training class https://www.tn-data.se
    /// </summary>
    public class BackChannelListener : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public BackChannelListener() : base(new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BackChannelListener");
            Console.WriteLine("@@@@ SendASync: " + request.RequestUri);

            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            var result = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            result.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                sw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("@@@@ success: " + result.IsFaulted);
                Console.WriteLine("@@@@ loadtime: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("@@@@ url: " + request.RequestUri);

                Serilog.Log.Logger.ForContext("SourceContext", "BackChannelListener")
                                  .ForContext("url", request.RequestUri)
                                  .ForContext("loadtime", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms")
                                  .ForContext("success", result.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                                  .Information("Loading IdentityServer configuration");
            });

            return result;
        }
    }

}

Hope this helps.
In AddOpenIDConnect, and if it redirects to the wrong URL, then you can override this by addding this event handler
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "https://localhost:7001/connect/authorize";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

To get logout to work, you first have to modify these rather "hidden" settings in the UI:
public static class LogoutOptions
{
    public static readonly bool ShowLogoutPrompt = false;
    public static readonly bool AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = true;
}

If that does not work, you need to ensure in the logs that the ID-token sent to IdentityServer during logut is actually accepted. If you get this error "JWT token validation error: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed" then you need to tweak the issuer value.
I was curious myself how to dockerize IdentityServer properly, so I am working on a blogpost, but that one will be published in 2-3 week time. In the meantime, you can peek at the source code here: https://github.com/tndataab/PublicBlogContent/tree/main/IdentityServer-in-Docker
There will be a final source folder with everything working later today or tomorrow.

Now i'm getting this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://app.service.identity'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://app.service.identity'. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors

Logs you provided
BackChannelListener
2024-10-09 16:37:58 @@@@ SendASync: http://app.service.identity/
2024-10-09 16:37:59 @@@@ success: True
2024-10-09 16:37:59 @@@@ loadtime: 278
2024-10-09 16:37:59 @@@@ url: https://app.service.identity/
2024-10-09 16:37:59 [13:37:59 INF] Loading IdentityServer configuration

I fixed errors above but now I'm getting the same error again, that it can't parse the data.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://app.service.identity'. Exception: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0
LOGS:
SendASync: http://app.service.identity/
success: False
loadtime: 285
url: https://app.service.identity/

If you use my  BackChannelListener , you should be able to capture the data it received before it is forwarded to the OpenIDConnect system. So, please print it out to the console (the response body) and see what you get back instead. This is one of the core benefits of using this tool.

I fixed all the previous errors, now it returns everything to me as it should and in the logs I see the json I need, but it redirects me again to the app.service.identity address in the browser, which clearly exists only inside the docker. I have specified in AddOpenIdConnect the address for authority "https://localhost:44384" and for MetadataAddress "http://app.service.identity/.well-known/openid-configuration"

Also, if I manually change the redirect link host to https://localhost:44384 then everything works I go to the login page, log in and I am redirected back to the client page and I am authorized. I need to find the option how to change the redirect link, for scope I specified it but it doesn't work

What is the problem with scope? and redirect?

I set up the right link "https://localhost:44384", but it still redirects me to app.service.identity

SEe the end of my answer above.

Yes, that worked, thank you. Do you know how I can return the user to the client host after logout? Right now I'm still on the Duende Server page after logout.

See my updated answer.
